# apt-get download package throws error 404 Not found

Tags: apt, ros

I am trying to download ros package ros-kinetic-desktop using `apt-get`. I have set the sources.list and the authentication key as well. However, I am encountering an error that says:

```
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 ros-kinetic-desktop arm64 1.3.0-0xenial-20170303-020026-0800 404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
W: Can't drop previleges for downloading as file 'home/sam/ros-kinetic-desktop_1.3.0-0xenial-20170303-020026-0800_arm64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run(13: Permission)
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-desktop/ros-kinetic-desktop_1.3.0-0xenial-20170303-020026-0800_arm64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
```

PS:`sudo apt-get download ros-kinetic-desktop` is the exact command I'm using.

Can someone please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am not supposed to use `sudo apt-get update` to update my entire cache ( especially the system packages) because the updated packages will crash my proprietary drivers. So, in order to just update the repositories I require, I manually added the ros repository to software and updates applet instead of using `apt-get update`. This way I am able to directly install the ros packages using `install` but unable to download them and manually install later.

Comment: Is their a difference between the package you want an `ros-desktop` package?

Comment: Is `download` a package name?

Comment: @MarkKirby the package I am downloading is "ros-kinetic-desktop"

Comment: @George `download` is the command that goes with `apt-get`, just like `install` but only downloads the package to a certain location and the package has to be manually installed later. `ros-kinetic-desktop` is my package.

Comment: Yes I remember now thanks for the refresher...

Comment: Use this syntax `apt-get -d install ros-kinetic-desktop` you will then find the deb at `/var/cache/apt/archives` AFAIK it won't install it.

Comment: It seems to be installing as well. I tried simulating your command, it's working just like `install`.

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

(with `sudo`) to make sure the package list is up to date.

Then use just

```
apt-get download ros-kinetic-desktop
```

(without `sudo`)

If you use `sudo` then `apt-get` will download the file not as root but user `_apt` for security reasons. As `_apt` doesn't have write permission in `home/sam/` you get this error.

Comment: I edited my question to add why I cannot use `sudo apt-get update`. Can you please look into that and let me know if there's a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of why and how it happened, but restarting the system did the trick! Although it throws the warning ( as above ), the package got downloaded.